# change the border radius of ubuntu launcher items

Tags: unity, launcher, themes, css

Possibly, I know what to edit, but I am not sure which file to edit to increase the border-radius of launcher items background.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10; Ambience theme. Kindly help.

**Edit:**

[image: Launcher theme background]

I am talking about the squarish background of the icons. Please, see icons are circular with square background. I want to make that background circular as well.

Comment: You can't really change the border radius since those are icons in the background. A workaround would be to create new rounded icons then backup and replace the current launcher icons located at `/usr/share/unity/icons`

Comment: @Parto, Could you add that  as answer when it get opened.  You deserve my vote. BaRud, exactly these icons `ls /usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_icon*`

Comment: @user.dz Mhhh, I can't. The question has been put on hold. No worries though, it is cool. Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: Thnaks, but is it possible to change them by user? eg, like icons in .icon? or i guess i need to put them in ~/.local/share/unity/icons